# Why does Javascript's regex.exec() not always return the same value?

Tags: javascript, regex

In the Chrome or Firebug console:

```
reg = /ab/g
str = "abc"
reg.exec(str)
   ==> ["ab"]
reg.exec(str)
   ==> null
reg.exec(str)
   ==> ["ab"]
reg.exec(str)
   ==> null
```

Is exec somehow stateful and depends on what it returned the previous time? Or is this just a bug? I can't get it to happen all the time. For example, if 'str' above were "abc abc" it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 283, accepted):

A JavaScript `RegExp` object is stateful.

When the regex is global, if you call a method on the same regex object, it will start from the index past the end of the last match.

When no more matches are found, the index is reset to `0` automatically.

---

To reset it manually, set the `lastIndex` property.

```
reg.lastIndex = 0;
```

---

This can be a very useful feature. You can start the evaluation at any point in the string if desired, or if in a loop, you can stop it after a desired number of matches.

---

Here's a demonstration of a typical approach to using the regex in a loop. It takes advantage of the fact that `exec` returns `null` when there are no more matches by performing the assignment as the loop condition.

```
var re = /foo_(\d+)/g,
    str = "text foo_123 more text foo_456 foo_789 end text",
    match,
    results = [];

while (match = re.exec(str))
    results.push(+match[1]);
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/pPW8Y/

---

If you don't like the placement of the assignment, the loop can be reworked, like this for example...

```
var re = /foo_(\d+)/g,
    str = "text foo_123 more text foo_456 foo_789 end text",
    match,
    results = [];

do {
    match = re.exec(str);
    if (match)
        results.push(+match[1]);
} while (match);
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/pPW8Y/1/

Comment: You can also reset it with `reg.exec("")` because it only retains the state if you pass the same string

Comment: It might be a good thing to include a `while` loop example, as this demonstrates the usefulness of this particular feature.

Comment: @Esailija @squint that's not entirely true. If you use the same regex to match against different strings, then the `lastIndex` remains set to where it was in the first string. I ran into this problem today.

Comment: @grammar: Not sure what you mean. [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gqrt4mhL/1/) that uses the same regex on two different strings. On the second string it continues on from the `.lastIndex` given when searching the first string. The regex object is oblivious to the string it's searching. If that behavior is what you meant, then what do you mean by *"not entirely true"*.

Comment: ...oh, are you talking about Esailija's *"only retains state if you pass the same string"* comment? Yeah, that's not right. His technique resets it because it fails to find a match in an empty string. Maybe there's some case where it doesn't reset? I wouldn't use that technique anyway.

Comment: @squint yeah sorry I wasn't very clear. I meant if you use the same regex _object_ to test against multiple strings, then that instance will have the `lastIndex` set to wherever the match was in the first string, when you try to compare with the next.

Comment: @squint After re-reading, I realize that you already pointed out that the same regex instance will retain state when the `g` flag is used. This is where I was having trouble.

Comment: In case anyone has read this far, here's a fiddle to further explain my plight (which is explained by @squint's answer above): http://jsfiddle.net/grammar/k2hxsq8d/2/

Comment: @grammar: Yeah, that's a common gotcha with these stateful regexp objects. If you want to do one search per string using the same regexp object, then you'll need to reset it before each search. You could also use `string.match(re)`, which should avoid the issue.

Comment: Sorry, but you can compress all of them to 1 line: `var result = 'text foo_123 more text foo_456 foo_789 end text'.match(/foo_(\d+)/g);`

Comment: @Mr.Wolf: I think you're missing the point. The point was to give  a demonstration of how `.lastIndex` can be used. In other situations, a single `.match` call won't work, so `.lastIndex` can be useful. Also notice that you're getting the `foo_` with the numbers instead of just the numbers.

Comment: I did not know you can set the lastIndex. It is like using indexOf + fromIndex with regex. All I need to write a simple and fast parser. :-)

Answer (score 37):

From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

> If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the exec method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string. When you do so, the search starts at the substring of str specified by the regular expression's lastIndex property (test will also advance the lastIndex property).

Since you are using the `g` flag, `exec` continues from the last matched string until it gets to the end (returns `null`), then starts over.

---

Personally, I prefer to go the other way around with `str.match(reg)`

Answer (score 14):

#### Multiple Matches

If your regex need the `g` flag (global match), you will need to reset the index (position of the last match) by using the `lastIndex` property.

> reg.lastIndex = 0;

This is due to the fact that `exec()` will [stop on each occurence so you can run again on the remaining part](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Description). This behavior also exists with `test()`) :

> If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the exec
>   method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string.
>   When you do so, the search starts at the substring of str specified by
>   the regular expression's lastIndex property (test will also advance
>   the lastIndex property)

#### Single Match

When there is only one possible match, you can simply rewrite you regex by *omitting the `g` flag*, as the [index will be automatically reset to `0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex).