# JS RegExp matches in FireBug... but not JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, regex, firebug, jsfiddle

I'm pretty stumped as to what's wrong with the following regular expression:

```
var // this regex digests a string into leading whitespace,
    // content text, and trailing whitespace.
    lineRegex = /^(\s*)(\S.*\S|\S)?(\s*)$/g,
    /* ... */;
```

`lineRegex` is supposed to match *anything*.  There is not even one required character, and if there are characters in the string, they are all either white space or not white space.  When I paste the exact regex into FireBug console and add `.exec("")`, I get the expected result, `["", "", undefined, ""]`.  But in my JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Lay9k/9/) I have:

```
try {
    var sections = lineRegex.exec(lineTxt),
        rawLeadingWs = sections[1] || "",
        contentText = sections[2] || "",
        importantTabs = rawLeadingWs.replace(
            oneTabWorthOfSpaces, "\t"
        ),
        tabsAndAligningSpaces =
            aligningTabRegex.exec(importantTabs),
        // I don't like this as much as Lint does.
        importantWsLength = 
            (tabsAndAligningSpaces[1] || "").replace(/[^\t]/g, "")
            .length * spacesPerTab +
            (tabsAndAligningSpaces[2] || "").length;
} catch (wtf) {
    console.log({
        lineText: lineTxt,
        sections: sections,
        rawLeadingWs: rawLeadingWs,
        contentText: contentText,
        importantTabs: importantTabs,
        tabsAndAligningSpaces: tabsAndAligningSpaces,
        importantWsLength: importantWsLength
    });
    throw wtf;
}
```

and I get `sections is null` when `lineTxt` is `""`.  So what gives?

Comment: why use regex if you want to match anything?

Comment: @Anirudh I want it to match everything - the important part is the captures.  It divides the string into leading whitespace (`[1]`), content (`[2]`), and trailing whitespace (`[3]`).

Comment: @Anirudh (and that's beside the point - it isn't matching anything anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `lastIndex` property of the regex is not reset properly.

Here's a related issue: [Why does Javascript's regex.exec() not always return the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477415/why-does-javascripts-regex-exec-not-always-return-the-same-value)

`reg.lastIndex = 0;` from one of the answers seems to fix it.