# RegEx is not working with backslash in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to validate strings with following pattern.
starts with 3 digits followed by hyphen followed by 2 digits and ends with 4 digits.
eg : 123-45-6789
I need to pass the pattern to a RegExp object as a string variable (I am getting the pattern value from a html element attribute ), hence I have escaped the RegExp with double slashes. To my surprise, I am seeing weird results.

```
var pattern = "^\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}$";
var inputRegex = new RegExp(pattern, "g");
console.log(inputRegex.test('132-45-7899')); //True
console.log(inputRegex.test('132-45-7899')); //False
console.log(inputRegex.test('132-45-7899')); //True
console.log(inputRegex.test('132-45-7899')); //False
```

What am I doing wrong here? and what is the reason for this inconsistent results?

EDIT:
Now I understood why the results are inconsistent , but my actual problem remained unsolved.
HTML elem is like below

SCENARIO 1:

```
<input data-val-regexp="^\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}$" id="ticketNumber">

var regexPattern = input.attr("data-val-regexp");
var inputRegex = new RegExp(regexPattern);
return inputRegex.test('123-45-6789'); // False
```

When I inspected, the inputRegex.source is "^\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}$"

SCENARIO 2:
If I assign the regexPattern with string literals everything works fine.

```
var pattern = "^\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}$";
var inputRegex = new RegExp(pattern);
console.log(inputRegex.test('132-45-7899')); //True
```

In the above case inputRegex source value is "^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$"

Why is the backslash escaped in the second scenario, where as it didn't in the first scenario? What needs to be done in order to make scenario 1 work?

Comment: You should open a new question with the actual problem, since that's not what you asked and this has been closed. But HTML doesn't do backslash-escaping; if you want a literal backslash inside a double-quoted string, just put a backslash. As it is, you're getting a regex looking for backslash-d instead of digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're creating the regular expression with the `g` flag, it remembers where it left off and starts matching there, instead of at the beginning, the next time you call `test`.  See [Why does Javascript's regex.exec() not always return the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477415/why-does-javascripts-regex-exec-not-always-return-the-same-value).

Comment: thanks for the reference, I understood why the results are not consistent. My actual problem remained unsolved, please see my edit to this question.