# Regular expression exec function does not work multiple times

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var ts = "00:00:06,705";

var regularExpression = /([0-9]+):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}),([0-9]{3})/g;
var parsedTs1 = regularExpression.exec(ts);
var parsedTs2 = regularExpression.exec(ts);
```

The parsedTs1 shows a right result, but the parsedTs2 variable has null after running this script.

But when we removed the last 'g' character at the end, this works well.

The option flag g means, according to the document, global search, which is nothing to do with this case.

How can we use the defined regular expression string multiple times to match strings?

Comment: What is the value stored in `var parsedTs1`

Comment: use `.test` or `String#search` for the reason given in the answer below

Comment: The `/g` flag allows the regex to iterate through multiple, non-overlapping matches within the same string.  When it returns `null`, it's telling you there are no more matches.

Answer (score 6):

Quote from [`here`](http://bjorn.tipling.com/state-and-regular-expressions-in-javascript):

> Regular expression objects maintain state. For example, the exec
>   method is not idempotent, successive calls may return different
>   results. Calls to exec have this behavior because the regular
>   expression object remembers the last position it searched from when
>   the global flag is set to true.

If you want to call it multiple times you can manually reset the last index after each call:

```
var parsedTs1 = regularExpression.exec(ts);
regularExpression.lastIndex = 0;
var parsedTs2 = regularExpression.exec(ts);
```

Comment: A better quote and explanation can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477415/why-does-javascripts-regex-exec-not-always-return-the-same-value.