# Pushing an object to an array makes it undefined--Scoping issue?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, undefined, push

I'm writing a web scraper that uses regex to extract information in a paragraph and store it in an object. Then I add the object to an array. Here's my full code:

```js
function scrapeCourseData(htmlString) {
  // scrapes a specific department's course list 

  var tempArr = [];

  console.log(tempArr); // outputs '[]' 

  $ = cheerio.load(htmlString);

  // #coursestextcontainer contains the actual information for every single course listed in a department                           
  $('#coursestextcontainer').find('.courseblock').each(function(i, elem) {
    // finds all divs of type courseblock, iterates though each of them,
    // extracting course information from children. 

    console.log('courseblock ' + (i + 1));

    var courseText = $('strong', '.courseblocktitle', elem).text(); // Gets the text that will be parsed 

    var regex = /([A-Z]{4}\s[A-Z]{1,2}\d{4})\s(.*?)(?:\.*)(\d{1,2}(?:\.?|-?)\d{0,2}\spoints?)/g;
    var regexGroups = Object.freeze({
      NUMBER: 1,
      NAME: 2,
      CREDITS: 3
    });

    var match, course;

    while ((match = regex.exec(courseText)) !== null) { // when regex.exec returns null, no more matches, and loop stops.
      course = {
        number: match[regexGroups.NUMBER],
        name: match[regexGroups.NAME],
        credits: match[regexGroups.CREDITS]
      };

      tempArr.push(course); // doesn't work-- result is array full of 'null'
      console.log(course); // but this outputs as a valid object, e.g. { number: 'AFAS W3030'... }
    }

  });

  console.log("Complete tempArr: " + tempArr); // outputs [object Object],[object Object],[object Object], etc. 

  for (var j of tempArr) {
    dataJSONObject.push(tempArr[j]);
    console.log('\ntempArray at ' + j + ': ' + tempArr[j]); // outputs [object Object]: undefined
  }

  console.log('\n');
}
```

When I first define `tempArr` as `[]` and output it to the console, I get the expected result `[]`.

The objects I form from regex matches are also valid as expected at runtime.

However, when I try to push those objects to `tempArr`, and then print `tempArr`, it outputs as `undefined`.

I've been poking around other stackoverflow questions and I'm pretty sure my problem is that when I'm pushing to `tempArr`, I'm doing so outside of its scope. I've tried moving around where I declare `tempArr` (e.g. by putting it outside its function to make it global), but I still get `undefined` after pushing. What am I missing?

Comment: tempArray is `JSON` instead of `console.log("Complete tempArr: " + tempArr);` try `console.log("Complete tempArr: " + JSON.stringify(tempArr));`

Comment: I think you need to manually set `reg.lastIndex = 0;` . Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477415/why-does-javascripts-regex-exec-not-always-return-the-same-value) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects you're pushing into the array are there, you're just reading out of the array incorrectly. A [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop doesn't put the index value in the variable you supply, it puts the ***value***. This explains why `tempArr[j]` is `undefined`.

Change your `for...of` loop to this:

```
for (var j of tempArr) {
    dataJSONObject.push(j);
    console.log('\ntempArray: ' + j);
}
```

Also, another way to put all the elements of one array into another is to use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
dataJSONObject.push(...tempArr);
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! The only other thing I had to do was stringify the `j` value inside `console.log()`. (I think `console.log({object})` implicitly calls `stringify()` on the passed object, but `console.log('string' + {object})` doesn't, because after concatenation the input is `string` instead of `JSON`.)