# Javascript regex grouping strange behavior: matches only on second attempt

Tags: javascript, regex

Really struggling to find the right wording for this issue, I am sure the answer is posted somewhere and has to do with not understanding fully how [RegExp.prototype.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Using_exec()_with_RegExp_literals) works.

I have a large object with keys that are strings and follow this pattern. `"foo.bar.baz": 'test'` where each segment is of arbitrary length, and all the keys start with foo, but the rest vary. I need to construct an array of all of the middle segments, ie. 'bar' in this example. To do this I am using a simple regex grouping.

`const myRegex = /foo\.([^\.]*)\./g`

String starts with foo, followed by a ".", and then capture everything until the next ".".

Iterating over the object with the keys described above, I want to append the middle section (bar) to an array each time, excluding duplicates.

```
for(const key in myObject){           //loop over each key in the object
  const matches = []
  match = myRegex.exec(key)
  if (match) {
    if (matches.indexOf(match[1]) === -1) {    //exclude duplicates
      matches.push(match[1])
    }
  }
```

The strange behavior is the fact that this only works for all of the second segments that have more than one occurrence. For example given the folowing object.

```
{
    'foo.bar.bar': 'test',
    'foo.bar.baz': 'test',
    'foo.baz.bar': 'test',
    'foo.baz.baz': 'test',
    'foo.bam.bar': 'test'
}
```

Only bar, and baz get pushed to matches. If `foo.bam.baz: 'test'` is added to the object, bam is matched and pushed to the array. If one of the `foo.bar.x` or `foo.baz.x` is removed, then that key is not pushed. It appears to only be matching on the second attempt, and I cannot figure out why.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't a simpler approach be to split the string on period to get the different segments? https://jsfiddle.net/g8acfL88/

Comment: dude i found it... im confused too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477415/why-does-javascripts-regex-exec-not-always-return-the-same-value

Comment: Don't use the `g` modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` to get property values of object, `.map()` to iterate properties, `RegExp` `/^foo\.|\.\w+$/g` to match `"foo"` and `"."` followed by one or more word characters followed by end of string, `Set` to remove duplicates from resulting collection, and then convert `Set` to array

```js
const o = {
    'foo.bar.bar': 'test',
    'foo.bar.baz': 'test',
    'foo.baz.bar': 'test',
    'foo.baz.baz': 'test',
    'foo.bam.bar': 'test'
}

let matches = [...new Set(Object.keys(o).map(prop => 
                prop.replace(/^foo\.|\.\w+$/g, "")))];

console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like regex objects are stateful:

```
var myRegex = /foo\.([^\.]*)\./g;

console.log(myRegex.exec("foo.bar.bar"))
console.log(myRegex.exec("foo.bar.bar"))
console.log(myRegex.exec("foo.bar.bar"))
console.log(myRegex.exec("foo.bar.bar"))
console.log(myRegex.exec("foo.bar.bar"))
console.log(myRegex.exec("foo.bar.bar"))
console.log(myRegex.exec("foo.bar.bar"))
console.log(myRegex.exec("foo.bar.bar"))
console.log(myRegex.exec("foo.bar.bar"))
```

---

```
(2) ["foo.bar.", "bar", index: 0, input: "foo.bar.bar"]
null
(2) ["foo.bar.", "bar", index: 0, input: "foo.bar.bar"]
null
(2) ["foo.bar.", "bar", index: 0, input: "foo.bar.bar"]
null
(2) ["foo.bar.", "bar", index: 0, input: "foo.bar.bar"]
null
(2) ["foo.bar.", "bar", index: 0, input: "foo.bar.bar"]
```

Comment: The key was as Bamar stated with the g modifier. Works as intended removing that.