# Javascript Boolean Operator Confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, boolean, boolean-operations

I have a few lines of javascript code as below:

```
var str = '////';
var re = /^\/+$/g 
console.log(str && re.test(str), str && !re.test(str));
```

The output of the code in `Node.js` are `false, false` and in `Chrome` Client side are `true, true`

I'm quite confused and would anyone help to understand:

1. Why the two boolean statements are both evaluated to `true` or `false` while they are meant to be opposite?
2. What's difference between `Chrome` and `Node.js` in evaluating the two boolean statements?

Comment: The code in Node seems to evaluate to `true` and `true` for me

Comment: Pretty sure your problem comes from re-using the global regular expression

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477415/why-does-javascripts-regex-exec-not-always-return-the-same-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) (emphasis mine):

> As with `exec()` (or in combination with it), `test()` called multiple
>   times on the same **global** regular expression instance will advance past
>   the previous match.

So, since your regular expression is global, the following happens:

```js
var str = '////';
var re = /^\/+$/g;

console.log(re.test(str)); // "true" — matches and regex advances
console.log(re.test(str)); // "false" — remainder no longer matches
```

In comparison, for a non-global expression:

```js
var str = '////';
var re = /^\/+$/;

console.log(re.test(str)); // matches, "true"
console.log(re.test(str)); // matches, "true"
```

Note: for the code in your question, I get the same output in Node as I do in Chrome and in Firefox: `true true`.

Comment: Thank you! That explains. The reason why I get `false false` in node is because my original code logged the re.test(str) before the two && operator.

Answer (score 1):

I think it doesn't seem to be an answer, but **Node.js** hereby outputs:

```
true true
```

Here's a terminal console.

```
PS E:\DevRoom\Kindy> node
> str = '////'
'////'
> re = /^\/+$/g
/^\/+$/g
> console.log(str && re.test(str), str && !re.test(str))
true true
undefined
>
```

[image]

**I bet it comes from re-using the global regular expression consequently.**

```
var regex1 = RegExp('foo*');
var regex2 = RegExp('foo*','g');
var str1 = 'table football';

console.log(regex1.test(str1));
// expected output: true

console.log(regex1.test(str1));
// expected output: true

console.log(regex2.test(str1));
// expected output: true

console.log(regex2.test(str1));
// expected output: false
```

Comment: Thank you. This is indeed the reason. Sorry I can't mark your post as an answer as the other post came in earlier than yours.

Comment: never mind, thanks. by the way, you could vote up for me anyway  ͡⚆ ͜ʖ ͡⚆

Comment: You're awesome!