# Empty value if regex match not found JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to extract any text characters at the beginning, and the following two numbers of a string. If the string starts with a number, I'd like to get an empty string value instead so the resulting array still contains 3 values.

---

String:
`'M2.55X.45'`

Code:
`'M2.55X.45'.match(/(^[a-zA-Z]+)|((\.)?\d+[\/\d. ]*|\d)/g)`

Expected:
`["M", "2.55", ".45"]`

Actual (correct):
`["M", "2.55", ".45"]`

---

String:
`'2.55X.45'`

Code:
`'2.55X.45'.match(/(^[a-zA-Z]+)|((\.)?\d+[\/\d. ]*|\d)/g)`

Expected:
`["", "2.55", ".45"]`

Actual:
`["2.55", ".45"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `/^([a-zA-Z]?)(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)[a-zA-Z](\d*(?:\.\d+)?)$/.exec("2.55X.45")` instead. This returns an array where the 1st element is the entire match, so you must access groups 1-indexed, for example, match[1] for the 1st value. You can try this out [here](https://regexr.com/51kjj).

Answer (score 1):

Your current regex uses an alternate clause (`|`), which creates different types of grouping depending on which alternate is matched.

Here's an example (cleaned up a bit) that creates explicit groups and makes the individual groups optional.

```js
const regex = /^([a-zA-Z]*)?(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)([a-zA-Z]+)(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)$/

console.log(regex.exec("2.55X.45"))
console.log(regex.exec("M2.55X.45"))
```

Note that I've removed the `g` flag, so the regex's [state isn't preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477415/why-does-javascripts-regex-exec-not-always-return-the-same-value).

I've also used `exec` instead of `match` to [not discard capture groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214754/what-is-the-difference-between-regexp-s-exec-function-and-string-s-match-fun).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this pattern

```
(\D*)(\d+(?:\.\d+))\D+(\.\d+)
```

[image]

```js
let finder = (str) => {
  return (str.match(/^(\D*)(\d+(?:\.\d+))\D+(\.\d+)/) || []).slice(1)
}

console.log(finder('M2.55X.45'))
console.log(finder("2.55X.45"))
```