# RegExp object won't execute more than once, why?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I stored a RegExp object in a variable and used it for mapping an array of strings into an array of objects (parsed e-mail recipients), but it doesn't work, as if a RegExp object couldn't run its `.exec()` method more than once.

However, if I use a regular expression literal instead of the stored object, it works as intended.

**I cannot understand the reason behind this behavior. Is it expected, or could it be a bug?**

The code:

```
const pattern = /^\s*(?<name>\w.*?)?\W+(?<address>[a-zA-Z\d._-]+@[a-zA-Z\d._-]+\.[a-zA-Z\d_-]+)\W*$/gi;
const input = "John Doe jdoe@acme.com; Ronald Roe <rroe@acme.com>";
const splitValues = input.split(/[\r\n,;]+/).map(s => s.trim()).filter(s => !!s);
const matchGroups1 = splitValues.map(s => pattern.exec(s));
console.log('Using pattern RegExp object:', JSON.stringify(matchGroups1, null, 2));
const matchGroups2 = splitValues.map(s => /^\s*(?<name>\w.*?)?\W+(?<address>[a-zA-Z\d._-]+@[a-zA-Z\d._-]+\.[a-zA-Z\d_-]+)\W*$/gi.exec(s));
console.log('Using literal regular expression:', JSON.stringify(matchGroups2, null, 2));
```

The output:

```
[LOG]: "Using pattern RegExp object:",  "[
  [
    "John Doe jdoe@acme.com",
    "John Doe",
    "jdoe@acme.com"
  ],
  null
]" 
[LOG]: "Using literal regular expression:",  "[
  [
    "John Doe jdoe@acme.com",
    "John Doe",
    "jdoe@acme.com"
  ],
  [
    "Ronald Roe <rroe@acme.com>",
    "Ronald Roe",
    "rroe@acme.com"
  ]
]"
```

## [test in TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/pt/play?#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)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Javascript's regex.exec() not always return the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477415/why-does-javascripts-regex-exec-not-always-return-the-same-value)

Comment: Thank you, it does. However, I already accepted an answer that points out that removing the `/g` flag solves the problem in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference lies in the `/g` flag that you've passed to both regexes. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags):

> [`RegExp.prototype.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) method with the `g` flag returns each match and its position iteratively.
>
> ```
> const str = 'fee fi fo fum';
> const re = /\w+\s/g;
>
> console.log(re.exec(str)); // ["fee ", index: 0, input: "fee fi fo fum"]
> console.log(re.exec(str)); // ["fi ", index: 4, input: "fee fi fo fum"]
> console.log(re.exec(str)); // ["fo ", index: 7, input: "fee fi fo fum"]
> console.log(re.exec(str)); // null
> ```

So `/g` on a regex turns the regex object *itself* into a funny sort of mutable state-tracker. When you call `exec` on a `/g` regex, you're matching and *also* setting a parameter on that regex which remembers where it left off for next time. The intention is that if you match against the *same* string, you won't get the same match twice, allowing you to do mutable tricks with `while` loops similar to the sort of way you would write a global regex match in Perl.

But since you're matching on two different strings, it causes problems. Let's look at a simplified example.

```
const re = /a/g;
re.exec("ab"); // Fine, we match against "a"
re.exec("ba"); // We start looking at the second character, so we match the "a" there.
re.exec("ab"); // We start looking at the third character, so we get *no* match.
```

Whereas in the case where you produce the regex every time, you never see this statefulness, since the regex object is made anew each time.

So the summary is: Don't use `/g` if you're planning to reuse the regex against multiple strings.

Answer (score 1):

See [Why does Javascript's regex.exec() not always return the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477415/why-does-javascripts-regex-exec-not-always-return-the-same-value). The issue is that `exec` is stateful: in other words it starts the next search after the index of the last one. You can avoid the issue by including `pattern.lastIndex = 0;` in the `map`; or else by using a literal as you suggest; or probably better, by removing the global (`/g`) flag on the regular expression, as per the other answer here.

```
const pattern = /^\s*(?<name>\w.*?)?\W+(?<address>[a-zA-Z\d._-]+@[a-zA-Z\d._-]+\.[a-zA-Z\d_-]+)\W*$/gi;
const input = "John Doe jdoe@acme.com; Ronald Roe <rroe@acme.com>";
const splitValues = input.split(/[\r\n,;]+/).map(s => s.trim()).filter(s => !!s);
const matchGroups1 = splitValues.map(s => {pattern.lastIndex = 0; return pattern.exec(s)});
console.log('Using pattern RegExp object:', JSON.stringify(matchGroups1, null, 2));
const matchGroups2 = splitValues.map(s => /^\s*(?<name>\w.*?)?\W+(?<address>[a-zA-Z\d._-]+@[a-zA-Z\d._-]+\.[a-zA-Z\d_-]+)\W*$/gi.exec(s));
console.log('Using literal regular expression:', JSON.stringify(matchGroups2, null, 2));
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/pt/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgQylApgJzDAvDA9APQB0IAqACgH4AeMBAWxQD5CB3AOhIoEoLCB1ANSUqCACai0KCBEYBtBAFoAXgEEFALUKi2AfQUBdAQAF5ytZu17DhNqdUatVgV34kAJLgDmASwDcAKFBIWG8wOABXWBwAIgApEAALTAAREBQYACtRNKMEYAY2UDpfGAAlcAQAG1EytJgqNDQcvIKixmiAoOgYCDhK7ygANSrwqWwYUIioNl7+qDJcWUI0QjAAGl9DXC42OgQ4MghsRh62KDRvOjIuHYAzb0rUNEPjmABCN4guTvBuvahgAkAOJNcJwCAARnGswGw0qowgu32LywJwA3ohkOgwGxKghoABJMCiFAAD3GAAYSpIoOEMPAkE8cWSUMBDlwAL7fQK-ECVFC4kCeMgAcgAqhBQp4GVj6aUUJ4AKKkuAwEAAIwyrKgAC4RWsYLEAMoAeQAcjNzlLvLcAJ5kf6AkEgMGQg1gcKVSoGgBMNx+wRgjuBoPBPuhfVhIykSIOR1ReCIpGEtAYzHYnB4-CE1DEEikMjs5i0ugMxiLDksZZsFYsThcfHcXm8bBZbK+3K6fIFlSFoolUpgc3QVRgkk8noQaBgZLgkmk3nAeoNxvNlouYB8dodSCdoYgPvdnu9MD93yAA)